# Unable to change selected option background color | React Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-select

i am using React select component for my dropdown selections. All functionality is working fine but i am unable to style the selected option background color when the option is selected from the dropdown. Tried few options but that too not working.

Below is the code for the same :-

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Select from "react-select";
import DataProvider from "context/DataContext";

export default function Compare() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);
  const {
    fromDate,
    toDate,    
  } = useContext(DataProvider);

  const customStyles = {           
    option: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,      
      color: "#1e2022",
      backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "rgba(189,197,209,.3)" : "white",
      padding: ".5rem 3rem .5rem .5rem",
      cursor: "pointer",
    }),       
    singleValue: (provided, state) => {
      const opacity = state.isDisabled ? 0.5 : 1;
      const transition = "opacity 300ms";

      return { ...provided, opacity, transition };
    },
  };

  const options = [
    {
      value: [
        moment(fromDate).subtract(1, "days"),
        moment(toDate).subtract(1, "days"),
      ],
      label: "Previous Day",
    },
    {
      value: [
        moment(fromDate).subtract(7, "days"),
        moment(toDate).subtract(7, "days"),
      ],
      label: "Previous Week",
    },
  ];

  const handleApply = (event) => {
    setSelectedValue(event);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      onChange={handleApply}
      options={options}
      styles={customStyles}
      placeholder="Compare to Past"
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Is none of your styles working or is it just the conditional operator that isn't.

Comment: @Archivec only the conditional one ... rest is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue regarding this. Apparently isSelected is only provided for multi-select. For single-select you could check for:

```
state.data === state.selectProps.value
```

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3817

**[Edit]**
This seems really weird but it appears that if you declared the options outside of the component it works. Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-6d6o3?file=/example.js). If you copied the options inside the render function then the styling won't work. It's not a problem with the values being Dates or moment objects or something as I tried setting the values as "1" and "2".

**[Edit 2]**
Ok emm.. I refactored it to be a functional component and it works with the options being inside the component. I'm guessing it may be a problem with utilizing hooks. Same sandbox to look at.

Comment: I tried this .. but still not working

Comment: It seems to work though. I forked the codesandbox from the issue and modified a bit [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-6d6o3?file=/example.js:589-613)

Comment: @Gurupalsingh Modified the answer to include some perhaps useful information, tested with your values.

Comment: but i want to use states inside my options which i'm getting from useContext ...!! Pheww !!

Comment: you're actually right ... i used static Options outside the component and it works ... but i want to use the dynamic states inside the Options...

Comment: @Gurupalsingh Yeah I provided another solution which also seems to work. But to be honest I'm not understanding much of the problem and the solution.

Comment: finally it works... thanks a lot :)

Comment: I just realized that you were already using functional components. In which case nothing is changed... magic happens sometimes..

Answer (score 10):

In order to change only the backgroundColor of the selected option try this:

```
option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "rgba(189,197,209,.3)" : "white",
}),
```

Comment: This works for me , after i manually refresh.

Answer (score 4):

Appending to @Nathan's answer above, include &hover if you don't want the background color to change on hover!

```
option: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#192E49' : 'inherit',
  '&:hover': { backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#192E49' : 'rgb(222, 235, 255)' }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the hasValue prop instead

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3817#issuecomment-547487812

```
backgroundColor: state.hasValue ? "rgba(189,197,209,.3)" : "white",
```

Comment: tried this ... but it actually changed the background of all the values.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible with CSS

To start you should add your prefix to the react-select CSS classes, like this

```
<Select
    classNamePrefix="an-simple-select"
    value={myValue}
    onChange={handleMyValueChange}
    options={myValueOptions}
/>
```

Then, you can add the following classes to your CSS file, code below set the background of selected to white and also colors with customer color the hovered option

```
.an-simple-select__option.an-simple-select__option--is-selected {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
.an-simple-select__option:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```